# Does AC-3 solve path consistency?

Tags: constraints, artificial-intelligence

When I read the pseudocode of `AC-3 in Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach`, I thought it solves path consistency as well as arc consistency. But the book says path consistency is solved by an algorithm `PC-2`. Did I miss something?

Why is `AC-3` not sufficient enough for solving path consistency?

Here's code for `AC-3`

```
function AC-3(csp) returns false if an inconsistency is found and true otherwise 
    inputs: csp, a binary CSP with components (X, D, C)
    local variables: queue, a queue of arcs, initially all the arcs in csp

    while queue is not empty do
        (Xi, Xj)←REMOVE-FIRST(queue) 
        if REVISE(csp, Xi, Xj) then
            if size of Di = 0 then return false
            for each Xk in Xi.NEIGHBORS - {Xj} do
                add (Xk, Xi) to queue 
    return true

function REVISE(csp, Xi, Xj) returns true iff we revise the domain of Xi 
    revised ← false
    for each x in Di do
        if no value y in Dj allows (x,y) to satisfy the constraint between Xi and Xj then 
            delete x from Di
            revised ← true
    return revised
```

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've figured out where the problem is. I misunderstood the meaning of path consistency.

I thought

`(1) {Xi, Xj} is path-consistent with Xk`

is equivalent to

`(2) Xi is arc-consistent with Xj, Xi is arc-consistent with Xk, and Xj is arc-consistent with Xk.`

That's why I thought `AC-3` was sufficient for solving path consistency. But it turns out not.

Give the meaning of (1) and (2):

(1) means that, for every pair of assignment `{a, b}` consistent with the constraint on `{Xi, Xj}`, there is a value `c` in the domain of `Xk` such that `{a, c}` and `{b, c}` satisfy the constraints on `{Xi, Xk}` and `{Xj, Xk}`

(2) could be explained in this way (which makes it easier to see the difference): for every pair of assignment `{a, b}` consistent with the constraint on `{Xi, Xj}` (Xi is arc-consistent with Xj, this one may not be accurate, but could make do), there is a `c` in the domain of `Xk` such that `{a, c}` satisfies the constraints on `{Xi, Xk`} (Xi is arc-consistent with Xk), and there is a `d` in the domain of `Xk` such that `{b, c}` satisfies the constraints on `{Xj, Xk}` (Xj is arc-consistent with Xk)

It's easy to see the difference now: in the explanation of (2), `c` and `d` could be different values in the domain of `Xk`. Only when `c` is equal to `d`, (2) is equivalent to (1)

So `AC-3` is only sufficient for solving (2), but it's too lax to solve path consistency

Who can tell me whether my understanding is right, this time? Thx :)

Answer (score 0):

It should be {b,d}satisfies the constraint on {xj,xk} .(xj is arc-consistent with xk).